# Contract object not supported for Push Topic channel

Tags: contracts, pushtopic

I am trying to create a push topic notification for the Contract object via the following code:

```
PushTopic pushTopic = new PushTopic();
pushTopic.Name = 'RefreshContract';
pushTopic.Query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Contract';
pushTopic.ApiVersion = 31.0;
pushTopic.NotifyForFields = 'Referenced';
insert pushTopic;
```

When I try to execute the code via the Dev Console(Execute anonymous window) so I can define the channel for this object, I receive the following error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. 
First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, 'Contract' is   not supported: [Query]
```

Any ideas? Is there any workaround to be able to receive push topic notifications for Contracts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Supported PushTopic Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/supported_soql.htm)

All custom objects are supported in PushTopic queries. The following subset of standard objects are supported in PushTopic queries: Account, Campaign, Case, Contact, Lead, Opportunity, Task.